# How to fetch key by value which is nested in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have below structure in MongoDB. I want to fetch a key by specific value.

ex. I want the result to be A1 if the value in v = 'Item Information'

I have few constraints through
1. key names A1, E1 = will be dynamic
2. value inside them 'v' will be always there

What should be the query for this?

[image]

Comment: Could you please share Document Json and your desired response.

Comment: @UpvotePlease since document is very large I can not share, but its an excel sheet imported, and I want to fetch A1 style header name based on its content.
lets say excel header A2 has content 'item name' so I want my output to be A2.
I am using js-xlsx which has sheet object that has structure given in above picture

Answer (score 1):

To deal with dynamic keys you can try as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        {
            $unwind: "$sheet"    
        },
        {
            $project: {
                "sheetData": { $objectToArray: "$sheet" }
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                 "sheetData.v": { $elemMatch: { v: 'Item Information' } },
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                result: "$sheetData.k"
            }
        }
    ])
```

Above query will give result keyName (A1) which contain `"v": "Item Information"`

The result will be as below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d020542c366c914650be72e"),
    "result" : [
        "A1"
    ]
}
```

I would like to let you know that I am trying all the above queries at my end and then only I am posting it along with the resulted JSON. So there could be only one possible mistake that we both are working with different document structure so please match your structure with below dummy Doc.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d020542c366c914650be72e"),
    "sheet" : [
        {
            "A1" : [
                {
                    "t" : "value"
                },
                {
                    "v" : "Item Information"
                },
                {
                    "r" : "value"
                },
                {
                    "h" : "value"
                },
                {
                    "w" : "value"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "E1" : [
                {
                    "t" : "value"
                },
                {
                    "v" : "value"
                },
                {
                    "r" : "value"
                },
                {
                    "h" : "value"
                },
                {
                    "w" : "value"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: one doubt, as K is not defined in the document, does k refers to keys 'A1','B1' in the mongo.i am talking about    --> result: "$sheetData.k"

Comment: Okay, so $objectToArray will handle it, I will try this once and respond

Comment: query is not giving result since V here is also a array which has t,v,r,h as a key and out of that key v has value "item information"

Answer (score 0):

Try as below to search Fetch Doc which contains "v": "Item Information" in "sheet.A1".

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$sheet"
    },
    {
        $match: {
             "sheet.A1": { $elemMatch: { v: 'Item Information' } },
        }
    }
])
```

Let me know if you need something else I will update my query.

I am working with dummy doc as below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d020542c366c914650be72e"),
    "sheet" : [
        {
            "A1" : [
                {
                    "t" : "value"
                },
                {
                    "v" : "Item Information"
                },
                {
                    "r" : "value"
                },
                {
                    "h" : "value"
                },
                {
                    "w" : "value"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "E1" : [
                {
                    "t" : "value"
                },
                {
                    "v" : "value"
                },
                {
                    "r" : "value"
                },
                {
                    "h" : "value"
                },
                {
                    "w" : "value"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Result of the above query will be as below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d020542c366c914650be72e"),
    "sheet" : {
        "A1" : [
            {
                "t" : "value"
            },
            {
                "v" : "Item Information"
            },
            {
                "r" : "value"
            },
            {
                "h" : "value"
            },
            {
                "w" : "value"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said in constraint no 1 , key names A1, E1 = will be dynamic, not necessary data will be in A1 it can be in A2, A3 or any column. Also above query is not returning result.

Comment: @AkshayNaik Above query is running very well, so please let me know your MongoDB version. Secondly, you should not make a dynamic key you should take a fixed key and put your dynamic values there. 
For example:-  sheet: [{ sheetName: "A1", sheetValue: [ {"t" : "value"}, {"v" : "Item Information"}] }].

Let me know if you can change your schema or i will write query one more time.

Comment: I am using mongoDB version 4.0.5, unfortunately I can not make my key fixed as data can be in any column in excel, I have already written client logic for same but I was looking for mongo query so I can  avoid client logic to iterate over huge list.